# Tool to implement c++ header functions in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-generation

Implementing a large set of c++ header functions is a hassle. Is there any particular tool that the community is using to generate function bodies based on the header. Search for a tool in the marketplace didn't yield any result.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking, there is now a VS Code plugin that does this.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.cpp-helper

It seems it appeared in 2020.